# Error in SQL with native query using jpa

Tags: java, sql, jpa

i need to write a complex query using JPA. i have written below query :

```
select temp2.role_id role_id, temp2.contact_id contact_id, temp2.account_id  account_id, temp2.username username, temp2.first_name first_name,  temp2.last_name  last_name, temp.email email  from (SELECT  role_id FROM    portal_role_privs START WITH granted_role_id in (select role_id from portal_role where name = :name) CONNECT BY granted_role_id = PRIOR role_id) temp3 inner join (select role_id, temp.contact_id contact_id, temp.account_id  account_id, temp.username username, temp.first_name first_name,  temp.last_name last_name, temp.email email  from portal_user_grp_privs pugp inner join ( select * from portal_user_data where account_id = :accountId ) temp on temp.contact_id = pugp.contact_id) temp2 on temp3.role_id = temp2.role_id.
```

and code :

```
EntityManager entityManager = EntityManagerUtil.getInstance().currentAsapEntityManager();
        logger.debug(LOGGER_PREFIX + "Obtained Entity Manager");
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(NATIVE_GET_ADMIN_CONTACTS);
        query.setParameter("accountId", accountId);
        query.setParameter("name", "admin");
        List<Object[]> accManagers = query.getResultList();
        List<AccountManagers> accountManagers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Object[] obj : accManagers) {
            AccountManagers accountMgr = new AccountManagers();
            accountMgr.setAccountId((String) obj[2]);
            accountMgr.setRoleType("admin");
            accountMgr.setContactId((String) obj[1]);
            accountMgr.setLoginName((String) obj[3]);
            accountMgr.setFirstName((String) obj[4]);
            accountMgr.setLastName((String) obj[5]);
            accountMgr.setEmail((String) obj[6]);
            accountManagers.add(accountMgr);

        }
        return accountManagers;
```

But this is throwing an error with "line 1:22: unexpected token: role_id: line 1:22: unexpected token: role_id".

Can somebody help in finding the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

your alias declaration is false : you need to use the AS keyword.

```
select temp2.role_id as role_id, temp2.contact_id as contact_id ...
```